# Auto-generate page numbers next to hyperlinks for printing

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, hyperlink, page-numbers

I have a large (780 page) document which contains a huge number of hyperlinks. These work fine when reading electronically, but this is ultimately going to be printed.  I'd like to turn the hyperlinked text into a page number instead of the section heading to which it refers - it's a children's pick-a-path book, so it's quite important they don't see the heading, only the page number. The links were originally created in Google Docs as bookmarks, but I'm now working in LibreOffice.

Please can someone tell me how to either:

- use the real page number in the section header text, and then update the hyperlinked text automatically?
- use only the real page number in the hyperlinked text?

I've been working between Google Docs and LibreOffice, but I can get access to MS Word if needed.

Headings and hyperlinks from Google Docs and LibreOffice:

[image: Screenshot showing headings and hyperlinks from GoogleDocs and LibreOffice]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of one of the pages?

Comment: Added as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a solution! It leans heavily on answers from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324367/how-to-use-findelementdocumentapp-elementtype-table-of-contents-to-get-and-pa
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727341/get-all-links-in-a-document
  Posting it all here so that it can be useful to other people (why oh why is this not an existing feature of all writing software?!)

This uses Google Scripts so you need to upload to your Drive and give the appropriate permissions before it will work.  It may also be the hackiest workaround ever, since you have to insert not one but TWO tables of contents into your document.  Google Docs has a weird "feature" (read: massive limitation) whereby you have to choose between a TOC with page numbers and a TOC with links.  This script basically combines the two into a dictionary so that all the links in the document can be annotated with the page number of the target.  External links are annotated with their URL.

In my document I have links, both to internal headings and external sites:
[image: screenshot of test document with internal and external hyperlinks]

I've also added two tables of contents using the Insert > Table of Contents menu option.  The first uses the page number option, the second uses the link option:
[image: screenshot of test document tables of contents]

When I run the script, the links in the document are annotated with their page numbers or URLs, so that the document is useful when in printed form:
[image: screenshot of successfully annotated links in the test document]

In Google Scripts I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Parse a Google Document, and annotate all hyperlinks with either the 
 * page number for the target (for internal headings and bookmarks) or 
 * the URL (for external websites and other documents).
 * 
 * This function relies on there being an open Document, which contains TWO
 * tables of contents (available through the Insert > Table of Contents menu).
 * The first TOC should be created using the option to include page numbers.
 * The second TOC should be creeated using the option to use links.
 */
function annotateHyperlinks() {

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // Create a dictionary using the two tables of contents: 
  // - the first must be created with page numbers
  // - the second must be created with links.
  // The returned `toc` a dictionary with keys which are the 
  // hyperlink URLs, and values which are also a dictionary, including
  // a `page` key to give the pagenumber.   
  var toc = assembleContentsDict(doc);

  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  for(var p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++) {
    labelLinksWithPageNumbers(paragraphs[p], toc);
  }
}

/**
 * Utility function called from `assembleContentsDict` to populate the table of contents dictionary with 
 * information from both TOCs.
 * 
 * @param {Element} toc: The TABLE_OF_CONTENTS element
 * @param {Object} contents: the dictionary to populate
 * 
 * @return {Object} contents: the populated dictionary
 */
function updateContentsList(toc, contents) {

  var numChildren = toc.getNumChildren();
  for (var j=0; j < numChildren; j++) {

    var tocItem = toc.getChild(j).asParagraph();
    var tocItemText = tocItem.getChild(0).asText().getText(); // Gets the whole line, including page number (if present)

    // Only overwrite the url when we have one
    var myUrl = tocItem.getLinkUrl();
    if(myUrl) {
      var item = contents[j];
      item.url = myUrl;
      contents[j] = item;
    }
    else {
      var mySplit = tocItemText.trim().split(/\s+/);
      var item = {};
      
      // The sectionNumber and sectionHeading are not currently used in this script, but if you wanted to 
      // replace the linked text with something consistent (ie: instead of "Go here" it could be "Section 1.3 Go here (page 2)")
      // then this is where that info comes from.  You'd also need to check that you do have numbered sections in your document,
      // otherwise this will need to be tweaked.
      item.page = mySplit.at(-1);  // last item is the page number
      item.sectionNumber = mySplit.at(0); // first item is the section number
      item.sectionHeading = mySplit.slice(1,-1).join(" "); // everything in between is the section heading

      item.url = '';
      contents[j] = item;
    }
  }
    // Return array of objects containing TOC info
  return contents;
}

/**
 * Assemble a dictionary-style table of contents, where the keys are the URL of each of the
 * headings.  The values are themselves also dictionaries, with keys of:
 *        - page (the page on which the heading appears)
 *        - sectionNumber (the number of the section)
 *        - sectionHeading (the title of the section)
 * The values are determined as:
 *        - sectionNumber (first item before whitespace in the TOC with pagenumbers)
 *        - page (last item before in the TOC with pagenumbers)
 *        - sectionHeading (everything in between)
 * 
 * @param {Element} doc: the current active document
 * 
 * @return {Object} contentsAsDict: the dictionary described above
 */
function assembleContentsDict(doc) {

  // Define the search parameters.
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS;
  var searchResult = null;
  var contents = {}; // This will be a dict of dicts, key is the bookmark url

  // Loop through both TOCs.  Note that this only works when there is one of each type ... 
  // ie: one with page numbers and one with links.
  while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    var toc = searchResult.getElement().asTableOfContents();
    contents = updateContentsList(toc, contents);
  }

  // Now turn the contents array into a dict with keys that are the heading URLs
  contentsAsDict = {};
  for (var key in contents) {
    contentsAsDict[contents[key].url] = contents[key];
  }

  console.log(contentsAsDict);
  return contentsAsDict;
}


/**
 * Label each internal link in the document (ie: those found within the table of contents)
 * with the page on which the link target is found.
 *
 * @param {Element} paragraph: The paragraph to operate on. 
 * @param {Object} toc: The table of contents dictionary created by 
 *                      assembleContentsDict() function
 * 
 */
function labelLinksWithPageNumbers(paragraph, toc) {
  
  for(var c = 0; c < paragraph.getNumChildren(); c++){

    var element = paragraph.getChild(c);
    if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {

      var textObj = element.editAsText();
      var text = element.getText();
      var inUrl = false;

      // Counting down from the end so that insertions don't affect the place in the string
      for (var ch=text.length-1; ch >= 0; ch--) {
        var url = textObj.getLinkUrl(ch);
        if (url != null) {

          // If we don't yet have a URL, it must start here.
          if (!inUrl) {
            inUrl = true;
            var curUrl = {};
            
            curUrl.element = element;
            curUrl.url = String( url );
            curUrl.startOffset = 0; // setting a default in case the link starts from the beginning of the paragraph.

            // Getting the page number from our TOC dict, if it is an internal link
            if(toc[curUrl.url]) {
              var linkText = " (page "+toc[curUrl.url].page + ") ";
              textObj.insertText(ch+1, linkText);
            }
            else {
              // Then it is an external link.  Include the URL address instead.
              var linkText = " ("+ curUrl.url +") ";
              textObj.insertText(ch+1, linkText);
            }
            
            // Updating the current position to skip over what we've just inserted
            curUrl.endOffsetInclusive = ch + linkText.length;
          }
          else {
            curUrl.startOffset = ch;
          }          
        }
        else {
          if (inUrl) {

            // Not any more, we're not.
            inUrl = false;
            textObj.setLinkUrl(curUrl.startOffset, curUrl.endOffsetInclusive, curUrl.url);

            curUrl = {};
          }
        }
      }
      // Takes care of links that extend to the first character in the paragraph
      if(inUrl) {
        textObj.setLinkUrl(curUrl.startOffset, curUrl.endOffsetInclusive, curUrl.url);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that:

- if you want to alter the link text to include the *actual* section heading and/or number (cf whatever the linked text was previously), this is possible (see comments inside the code).
- I haven't tested it on random bookmarks to images/tables/equations etc, only headings which appear in the tables of contents.

Answer (score 0):

### In Microsoft Word, you could use the PageRef field.

Here is a link to [Microsoft's documentation on that field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-pageref-field-bbda448f-7233-4aaa-b061-55ca4664c4d7).

> **Syntax**
>
> When you view the PageRef field in your document, the syntax looks
> like this:
>
> { PAGEREF Bookmark [* Format Switch ] }

If you are linking to a built-in heading style, you could also use Insert Cross-Reference, which allows you to choose to display the page number and insert as an unmarked hyperlink by default.

I do not know whether or not LibreOffice has the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the quick reply.  Unfortunately, the existing links are not in this format, and showing the underlying fields doesn't reveal anything at all for them!  I should have used cross-references in Word from the beginning, but now I'm stuck with a document in another format, so looking to fix that automagically if poss.  If I can't, then I'll have to manually change them all to cross-references ... which is Plan Z!